# converting .mov wrapper with amr_nb audio codec to aac/mp4a codec

Tags: android, iphone, audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am trying to implement a video messaging feature for cross platform(Android/iPhone) app.
Currently, the app on Android records the video with AMR narrowband in .mov wrapper and iPhone cannot play this video. The backend is centos 5.5 and I am wondering if ffmpeg is useful for transcoding this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ffmpeg should be able to do the transcoding.  Make sure you build your ffmpeg with support for both AMR and H.264/AAC and then you'll be able to convert using a command similar to this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -y -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -vpre baseline -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

This mp4 should play on both android and iphone.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mov -y -ar 44100 output.mov`
 worked for me (with libx264 and opencore-amr)